# Ajax navigation without #!

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

I have noticed that sites like http://hypem.com which is a full ajax site have now managed to scrap their #! ajax urls but maintained a full ajax site. How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with history.pushState, only in decent browsers though ;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Here's a jQuery plugin with a fallback for older browsers to a hashed URL:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history-js

Comment: So this wont change the url in the same way that window.location would? It wont refresh the page?

Comment: @pagewil: that's the idea. `pushState()` allows you to modify the URL of the page without reloading it.

Answer (score 5):

Some modern browsers support [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

However, if you want to support older browsers that are still popular, you should use the hash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has new History API. Demo is available at this url.
http://html5demos.com/history/

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js has a very good support for this.
Also history.js is plug able with jquery, mootools etc and supports HTML4 browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

simply include your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/binarymind/jquery-navigate/master/navigate.js" ></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.navigate.init();
});
</script>
```

after the include to jquery (1.7+) in the `<head>` and the plugin will ajax-navigate automaticaly in your website.

for any more customization, doc or answers you can go on github https://github.com/binarymind/jquery-navigate

hope it helps.

bastien